# Moodle webservice function to get course completion status

Tags: web-services, rest, moodle

I am trying to create a mobile application for Moodle. This involves creating and enabling webservice in moodle. I have succeeded in creating the webservice and able to get the courses and course details using the functions core_course_get_courses and core_course_get_contents.

Now I need to get the completion status of a course from moodle. Is there any function which can be used to do this. I have gone through the webservices and did not find any function that provides this data. Is there any external plugin to accomplish this? or any other help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time ago. I think that you have two ways to solve this problem:

1. [Develop a local webservice](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_a_web_service_to_a_plugin) that, inside Moodle, returns the completion course's status. The function to do that would be something along these lines:

   ```
   <?php
   require_once("{$CFG->libdir}/completionlib.php");
   $cinfo = new completion_info($course_object);
   $iscomplete = $cinfo->is_course_complete($USER->id);
   ?>
   ```
2. Create a webservice that, outside Moodle, gets the course's completion page, parse it, and returns the values back. This is the path I personally choosed (it is a bit dangerous though, because it is easily broken by UI updates of Moodle).

   I did it with Python. This is the code to get initially the web page:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

   username = 'USER'
   password = 'PASSWORD'
   wwwroot = 'wwwroot of your moodle'
   remember = 0;

   def get_nv_page(url):
       cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
       opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
       login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password, 'rememberusername': remember})
       opener.open(wwwroot + '/login/index.php', login_data)
       resp = opener.open(url)
       return resp.read()

   def get_completion_course(course_id):
       url = wwwroot + '/course/report/completion/index.php?course=' + str(course_id)
       return get_nv_page(url)
   ```

   And to parse it...

   ```
   import requests, re
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   def grab_completion_table(self, raw_doc):
       """ Convert an html course's completion page from moodle into a python list """
       list_video_activities = []
       completion_table = {}
       doc = BeautifulSoup(raw_doc)
       html_table = doc.find('table', id="completion-progress")
       activities = html_table.find_all('th', attrs={ 'class': 'criteriaicon'})

       for activity in activities:
           url = activity.find('a', href=re.compile('.*mod\/url\/view.*'))
           if url is not None:
               list_video_activities.append(url['title'])
           else:
               list_video_activities.append(False)

       user_rows = html_table.find_all('tr', id=re.compile('user-[0-9]*'))

       for user_row in user_rows:
           user_id = user_row['id'].split('-')[1]
           activities_completion_info = user_row.find_all('td', attrs={ 'class': 'completion-progresscell'})
           completion_user_table = []

           for i, video_activity in enumerate(list_video_activities):
               if video_activity != False:
                   activity_info = activities_completion_info[i].find('img')['title'].split(',')[1].strip()
                   activity_completion_info = activity_info.split(':')[1].strip()
                   # I put this: [ video_title, completion_status ] 
                   completion_user_table.append((video_activity, activity_completion_info))

           completion_table[user_id] = completion_user_table

       return completion_table
   ```

   With the data in Python, it's easy to add a webservice with it. I don't know if you can use python in your project, but I think this approach is replicable in other languages.

Comment: Just to also add that we'd love to get your web service in core and have us maintain it :) See http://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_contribute_a_web_service_function_to_core

Comment: The webservice is written in Python, I would have to rewrite it from scratch in PHP to insert it in Moodle :) anyway, I really appreciated your message; when I will develop a web service for Moodle, I'll seriously consider your "advice" :)

Comment: Ah apologies, I wasn't reading properly and saw your first option only  , which looked close enough to being a web service integratable to core :)

Comment: Thanks, We have decided to write a plugin to get the values